# How to send Email using gmail account in Asp.net WEB API

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to send bulk of emails through smtp server using gmail account, but i am facing issue like this: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ry1sm18393619pab.30 - gsmtp". I am using Asp.net c# console application.

here is my code which i am using:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EmailSend send = new EmailSend();
        send.Page_Load();
    }

    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"), new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
            msg.Subject = "Test link..";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string emailid = "abc@gmail.com";
            string password = "abc123";
            string host = "smtp.gmail.com";

            SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpclient.Host = host;
            smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpclient.Port = 587;

            smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailid, password);
            smtpclient.Send(msg);
            Console.WriteLine("A link has been send to you for resetting password. Check your mail! ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why this issue is coming. I have given correct credentials like: Emailid and password for gmail, i have changed port number also 25,587. If anyone has some sloution then it would be very helpful.